# Can't write the last part of a txt file to cout using ifstream

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream, cout, eof

The code below will print all of the text from the sample text file I'm using except for the last little snippet of it.  I think this has something to do with the eof or the byte size I'm using not working as I expect.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
int length;
char* buffer;

//get file stream and open local file.
ifstream stream;
stream.open("SampleFile.txt", ios::binary);
stream.seekg(0, ios::end);
length = stream.tellg();
stream.seekg(0, ios::beg);

//read stream 1024 bytes at a time until all bytes of file are used
buffer = new char[1024];
bool eof = false;
while(!eof)
{
    stream.read(buffer, 1024);
    cout.write(buffer, 1024);
    if(stream.eof())
        eof = true;
    //cout << i << endl;
    //cout.write(buffer, 1024);
}

stream.close();
delete[] buffer;
return 0;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I doubt that it's OK to read 1024 bytes into a buffer of size 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already know, you have a wrong size of buffer. The other thing is the read of less than 1024 characters (going to happen at the end if your file doesn't have exactly `n*1024` bytes). Take the advantage of `istream::gcount` which gives you number of characters extracted by last read:

```
char buffer[1024];
while(stream)
{
    stream.read(buffer, 1024);
    cout.write(buffer, stream.gcount());
}
```

Comment: I've actually edited it to `while(stream)` as in Rob's example, as it checks all flags, not only `eof` (as `stream.good()` does). You might want to check `stream.eof()` after the loop to see if it reached the end of file.

Answer (score 2):

1) You are not correctly calcuulating the size of the final buffer.

2) You are not correctly recognizing all of the possible error conditions.

Try:

```
while(stream) {
    stream.read(buffer, 1024);
    cout.write(buffer, stream.gcount());
}
```

---

**PS**. If you are really trying to copy the named file to standard out, there is a much easier way:

```
ifstream stream("SampleFile.txt", ios::binary);
std::cout << stream.rdbuf();
```

Comment: @Rob: even better: `while(stream.read(buffer, 1024)) { cout.write(buffer, stream.gcount()); }`

Comment: @Evan, what about `while(stream.read(buffer, 1024) && cout.write(buffer, stream.gcount());` ;-)

Comment: Or, as a one-liner: `std::cout << std::ifstream("sm.in").rdbuf();`

Comment: @Evan, @tomasz -- your loops are incorrect. The final call to read will set `eofbit` and `failbit`, and will never write out the final, partial, buffer. See http://ideone.com/LvYRU

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is that your last read doesn't happen to be exactly the size of your buffer. You need to handle that as a special case. For details, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/read/.

Oh, and it looks like your buffer is 8 bytes long but you read 1024 bytes. That's bad.

Comment: lol yeah sorry about the 8/1024 thing. i was trying to adapt this into an example question from an older test file I had and didn't change everything.  I meant it to be 1024 all over. I will try that link out and see what happens.

Comment: In case the stuff at that site is too long and boring for you, tomasz just posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the size of the file, why not read the entire file at once?

```
buffer = new char[length];

stream.read( buffer, length );
cout.write( buffer, length );

delete[] buffer;
```

Comment: i can't read the entire file at once because i need to send 1kB of data at a time over a network