# eof error reading pieces of text file and writing to boost.asio socket

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio, ifstream, eof

I'm trying to read a file 1kB at a time and write each piece of data to a socket using boost.asio.  The problem is that when I need to read the last piece of data from the text file and put it in the buffer, it doesnt seem to work.

I need a way to print the last part of the buffer without printing the whole buffer (because it contains leftovers from the previous iteration of the loop)

```
int portNumber = 2002;
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), portNumber));
tcp::socket socket(io_service);
acceptor.accept(socket);
boost::system::error_code ignored_error;

 int length;
char* buffer = new char[1025];//1024 bytes for data, 1 byte for seqNum
//get file stream and open local file.
ifstream stream;
stream.open("SampleFile.txt", ios::binary);
stream.seekg(0, ios::end);
length = stream.tellg();
stream.seekg(0, ios::beg);

 while (!stream.eof())
    {
        //char sequenceNumber = '0';

        stream.read(buffer, 1024);
        buffer[1024] = sequenceNumber;//set last pos to seq num
        boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(buffer),
                            boost::asio::transfer_all(), ignored_error);
               .
               .   //do other things
               .
    }
```

This will eventually write everything to the socket (assuming the client end is cooperating) except that a portion of the end of the file will get written twice.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740425/cant-write-the-last-part-of-a-txt-file-to-cout-using-ifstream/6740686

Answer (score 2):

1) You aren't correctly computing the size of the final buffer.

2) You aren't correctly testing the stream for error or eof conditions.

Try this:

```
while (stream)
{
    stream.read(buffer, 1024);
    buffer[1024] = sequenceNumber++;//set last pos to seq num
    boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(buffer, stream.gcount()),
                        boost::asio::transfer_all(), ignored_error);
    ...   
}
```

Comment: thats what I was looking for.  I knew about gcount() but I couldnt read the boost documentation well enough to see how I could use it. I'll try this out real quick and let you know how it goes. THANKS!

Comment: i tried out this code and it did the same thing as the code I posted. Not so sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @user754989 - Try to step through the loop in a debugger. How many times does it run? What is the value of `stream.gcount()`? Try to simplify your program. Use a small input file. Get rid of pieces of your program, one piece at a time, until either the bug goes away or becomes obvious.

Comment: I get the following error when compiling:  usr/include/c++/4.2.1/istream:476: note: candidates are: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::read(_CharT*, std::streamsize) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]   ... not sure exactly how to interpret that.  This is when I am using the std::vector as the buffer and the error is on the line "while(stream.read(buffer, 1024))

Comment: ok guys, im still confused.  I have put my server code here:
http://ideone.com/qzOTc
can someone look at it and tell me how to fix this problem? thanks again.

Comment: i just realized it is actually double printing the last part (not all of the last part, but most of it) which is still curious behavior... hmmm